# Spark SQL Update/Delete

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

Currently, I am working on a project using pySpark that reads in a few Hive tables, stores them as dataframes, and I have to perform a few updates/filters on them. I am avoiding using Spark syntax at all costs to create a framework that will only take SQL in a parameter file that will be run using my pySpark framework.

Now the problem is that I have to perform UPDATE/DELETE queries on my final dataframe, are there any possible work arounds to performing these operations on my dataframe?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

A `DataFrame` is immutable , you can not change it, so you are not able to update/delete.

If you want to "delete" there is a `.filter` option (it will create a new `DF` excluding records based on the validation that you applied on `filter`).
If you want to "update", the closer equivalent is `.map`, where you can "modify" your record and that value will be on a new `DF`, the thing is that function will iterate all the records on the `.df`.

Another thing that you need to keep in mind is: if you load data into a `df` from some source (ie. Hive table) and perform some operations. That updated data wont be reflected on your source data. `DF`'s live on memory, until you persist that data.

So, you can not work with `DF` like a sql-table for those operations. Depending on your requirements you need to analyze if Spark is a solution for your specific problem.